# How to write the "greater than symbol" in a HTML file using a batch file

Tags: html, batch-file

I was wondering if it is possible to use the "<" and ">" when writing to a HTML file from a  batch file. I need this so I can write certain things to html files.
I tried the following and it didn't work:

```
 ECHO </html> >>File.html
```

PS. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little messy, but you have to [*escape*](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) the `<` and `>` characters using `^`:

```
echo ^<html^> >> a.html

echo ^<body^>Hi^</body^> >> a.html

echo ^</html^> >> a.html
```

Result:

```
<html> 
<body>Hi</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the character by placing a carot sign (^) in front of "<" and ">".

```
echo ^</html^> >>File.html
```

Comment: It is "caret", not "carot"... **`;-)`**